# removing header and blank lines from a csv file

Tags: linux, csv, sed

I have a bunch of csv files coming in the form of a daily feed from some other system.

I have to remove the header and some optionally present blank lines from the files before loading it onto HDFS and building an external table on top of it.

Currently I have a two step process which works to remove the header and blank space before putting the file on HDFS

```
//remove blank lines
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file_20160802.csv

//remove header
sed -i 1d file_20160802.csv

//put file on HDFS
hdfs dfs -put file_20160802.csv /raw/abc/20160802/
```

Is there a way I can combine the two steps without creating any temporary files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine like this :

```
sed -i '1d; /^\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: Thanks heaps  @sat !!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -ni.bak '1!{/^$/!p}' file.csv
```

should also do the job and a backup with `file.csv.bak` will be created.

**What is this all about?**

- `1!` process the following commands except for line 1. `!` is negation.
- `/^$/` checks for an empty line.
- `!p` which follows the pattern check above would print the line if it is not empty because of the negation (`!`).
- The `-i` or the inplace edit option makes sure that changes are directly reflected in the file.

Comment: can you please explain what the 1!{/^$/!p} part does?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the effort!! This is in fact another solution for my problem!!